# Updating/appending to a .wav file in Python

Tags: python, audio, udp, wav, pcm

I have a stream of PCM audio frames coming into my Python script, and I am able to save blocks of these frames as .wav files as such:

```
def update_wav():
    filename = "test.wav"
    wav_file = wave.open(filename, "wb")
    n_frames = len(audio)

    wav_file.setparams((n_channels, sample_width, sample_rate, n_frames, comptype, compname))
    for sample in audio:
        wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(sample * 32767.0)))
    wav_file.close()
```

However, I'd like this to continually update as new frames come in. Is there way to writeframe in a way that appends to an existing .wav file? Right now I am only able to accomplish an overwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this with [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html), it actually seems to be the default functionality for their writing method.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

def update_wav():
    numpy_data = numpy.array(audio, dtype=float)
    scipy.io.wavfile.write("test.wav", 8000, numpy_data)
```

Comment: With the latest SciPy package (1.6.0) this behavior cannot be reproduced. scipy.io.wavfile.write will overwrite existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `wave` module in python's standard library:

```python
import wave 


with wave.open('my/file/path.wav', 'wb') as wavfile: 
    wavfile.setparams(channels, sample_width, framerate, number_of_frames, compression_type, compress_name)
```

Here is an example code to test that it works:

```python
import itertools
import wave
from IPython.display import Audio


filepath = "my/file/path.wav"

with open(filepath, 'rb') as in_wavfile:
    params = in_wavfile.getparams()
    data = in_wavfile.readframes(in_wavfile.getnframes())
    idata = iter(data)
    
with wave.open(filepath + '.out.wav', 'wb') as out_wavfile:
    out_wavfile.setparams(params)
    while wavdata := bytes(itertools.islice(idata, 100 * out_wavefile.getsampwidth())):
        out_wavfile.writeframes(wavdata)
        
Audio(fp + '.out.wav')
```

You can run that in a Jupyter notebook or cruft it for your needs.